# Use one Angular project to create another

Tags: angular

I have a completed Angular project called pageTemplate that I'd like to be able to use as a starting point for each new project but am not sure how to do it.

I tried copying the folder and renaming it as well as searching through out the folder to look for all occurrences of "pageTemplate" and renaming it accordingly. Got a "Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package" when doing ng serve in the new project folder."

After some research I saw it mentioned to remove the node_modules from the new project folder and do npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Then when doing ng serve I got the error "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error." and noticed it did not add node_modules to the new project.

After more research saw to do a cache clean and npm init. All this did was create a node_modules folder in the folder above my new project folder (I'm doing all my projects in a main folder called AngularDev).

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, but when you copy the project **do not copy** the following

- The `.angular` folder
- The `node_modules` folder
- The `package-lock.json` file

After copying the folder minus the above list, you should be able to find/replace all instances of your old application name with the new one. Mostly these will be in the `package.json` and `angular.json` files

Now just run `npm install` and it should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, just after I posted this I noticed doing the copying through visual studio code's file browser was not making copies of the tsconfigs, etc. in the folder. So I manually did the copy through explorer and then did the steps you mentioned and everything worked.

Comment: I would NOT remove package-lock.json. it ensures that all the node modules that would be installed are exactly like in the "working" project